# How to know which object is last in array? Angular ( angular-material tabs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have array of object

```
[{id: 1, name: home , path: 'home'}, {id: 2, name: contact , path: 'contact'}]
```

array can have many objects.
I have function which add object:

```
  addTab(selectAfterAdding: any) {
    if (!this.tabs.some(objectItem => objectItem.id == selectAfterAdding.id)) {
      this.tabs.push(selectAfterAdding);
    }
  }
```

Also function which delete and return router back.

```js
removeTab(index: number, event: Event) {
  this.tabs.splice(index, 1); 
  this._location.back();
}
```

html:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
      <a mat-tab-link
         *ngFor="let tab of tabs;let i = index;"
         [routerLink]="tab.path"
         routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" 
         [active]="rla.isActive"
         class="test"
         >
        {{ tab.name }}
        <span class="span-X-icon" (click)="removeTab(i)" >  delete </span> 
      </a>
    </nav> 

        <mat-panel-title routerLink="/home" (click)="addTab({ id: 1 , name: 'home' , path: 'home'})">
              Home page
        </mat-panel-title>
```

Problem is when delete tab which is not active a go to back route.. I don't know to do fix this. Maybe how to check the active route in url???

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of '[selectFocusedIndex](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabNav)' event or 'selectedIndex' property to keep track of active tab. Also add condition to check active tab in your remove tab function for navigating back to the previous route.

Comment: Hm can you hint me more details ? @Krisha